# Vanilla Javascript version of attr('selected', true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Without using JQuery how would I convert

```
$('#H10 option[value*="2"]').attr('selected',true).trigger('change')
```

into vanilla Javascript. I believe using dispatchEvent(new Event('')) would replace trigger() but I cant find anything for the attr() function.
When I tried to use :

```
document.querySelector('#H10 option[value*="2"]').setAttribute('selected', 'selected').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatchEvent'). Other things I have tried include using the selected() = true.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#H10 option[value*="2"]').setAttribute('selected', true)`

Comment: @Spectric that's missing the event dispatch

Answer (score 1):

Unlike jQuery's methods, all DOM methods don't return `this` necessarily, `setAttribute()` for instance returns `undefined`.
This means that you can't chain your calls like you were doing in jQuery.

You should store your element in a variable, set its attribute, and then call its `dispatchEvent` method.

```js
const option = document.querySelector('#H10 option[value*="2"]');
option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
option.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<div id="H10">
  <select>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
  </select>
</div>
```